# Add Bolded Days to a Month Calender

Tags: c#, calendar

I'm developing school management system in C#. net. And I needed to give user to add events by clicking a date in the calender and that date should be bold after adding. I tried below code but only last added date was bold. But I need to bold each selected days. Can somebody help me to add all selected days to Bolded Days array? I'll appreciate any help. This is my code.

```
//Create method for add bold days
public void boldDays()
        {
            List<DateTime> l = new List<DateTime>();


            l.Add(DateTime.Parse(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToLongDateString()));


            DateTime[] s = l.ToArray();
            monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = new DateTime[] { };
            monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = l.ToArray();
        }






//Executing method when a button click
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            boldDays();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you're adding only one date. You need to loop through your list of events. The following code might help:

```
public void boldDays()
{
    List<DateTime> l = new List<DateTime>();
    foreach (var event in savedEvents)
    {
        l.Add(event.Date);
    }
    monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = l.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you referred as "savedEvents". Please I didn't get that part.

Comment: You should create a list of saved events: `IList<DateTime> savedEvents = new List<DateTime>()` for instance. Then each time your user clicks on a date to add an event, you add it to the list: `savedEvents.Add(selectedDate)`. This way, you can iterate in your `boldDays` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding just starting date in array. Try this

```
public void boldDays()
{
    List<DateTime> l = new List<DateTime>();
    for(DateTime m = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start;m <= monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End; m = m.AddDays(1) )
    {
        l.Add(DateTime.Parse(m.ToLongDateString()));
    }


    //monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = new DateTime[] { };
    l.AddRange(monthCalendar1.BoldedDates); //If you want to preserve previously added dates then add previously added dates to list as  
    monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = l.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it still bold last added date!

Comment: Thanks lot for your answer. And it solved my problem too. But I have another question regarding to this. Is there a way to load above bolded days after re-opening the form? Because I need to show them bold after user opening the form again.

Comment: Save selected days in database and add code to show days in Form_Load.